# Не могу разобраться как получить данные товаров Woocommerce(Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Пытаюсь разобраться как получить данные товаров, а именно:

1. Название товара.
2. Описание товара.
3. Основное изображение товара.
4. Остальные изображение товара(галерея).
5. Цена товара.

Я пытался достать эти данные с помощью **get_posts**:

```
$posts = get_posts(Array('post_type'=>'product'));
foreach($posts as $post) {
  setup_postdata($post);
  the_title();
  the_id();
  the_time();
}
```

Но у меня не получается достать цену.

Так же я пытался достать данные с помощью **wc_get_products** и **WC_Product_Query**

```
$query = new WC_Product_Query( array(
    'limit' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'return' => 'ids',
) );
$products = $query->get_products();
var_dump($products);
```

Но в данном случае я получал лишь массив с **id** записей...
Как мне получить эти данные?

P.s. я пытался найти ответ в интернете. После того как я не нашел ответ я отправился читать документацию https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/index.html, но как-то не могу переварить как это должно работать. Буду рад если кто-то сможет объяснить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Товар - другой объект. Получив id поста, нужно получить объект "товар", а потом уже его цену.

```
$wc_product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
$price      = $wc_product->get_regular_price();
```

У объекта товар множество методов, с помощью которых можно получать информацию о товаре. Смотрите в файле `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php`

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно) А что на счет изображений? А хотя сначала посмотрю файл))

Comment: А почему в документации нет информации о get_regular_price() ?

Comment: Не знаю, я её практически не использую. Наверное, есть информация, не там искали.

Comment: А изображения - это те же attachments, как у постов WordPress

Comment: Вообще вы мне отличный совет дали, я открыл файл и тут 15 методов, даже те о которых я не знал) Вообщем я нашел get_gallery_image_ids - это ид изображений которые находятся в галереи

Comment: Ну галерея - да, средствами WC. А главное изображение товара - это то же самое, что Featured Image у обычного поста.

Comment: Вот метод для вывода главного изображения get_image :D

Comment: А можно как-то только url получить изображения?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82826/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-olishevskyalex).